# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The request object has been recycled and is no longer associated with this facade

Tags: java, web, vaadin, scheduler

I created a time function in Vaadin using a scheduler to update a label every second.

```
  if (getUI().isPresent()) {
            ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            UI ui = getUI().get();

            Runnable repeatedTask = () -> {
                if (ui.isAttached()) {
                    ui.access(() -> {
                        timeLabel.setText(
                                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.now()));
                    });
                }

            };
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(repeatedTask, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            ScheduledExecutorService shutdownSchedule = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            Runnable shutdownTask = () -> {
                scheduler.shutdown();
                shutdownSchedule.shutdown();
            };
            shutdownSchedule.schedule(shutdownTask, 3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
```

When I run the program locally, there are no issues, but in production, it displays this error message.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The request object has been recycled and is no longer associated with this facade
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.removeAttribute(RequestFacade.java:549) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.removeAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.removeAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:268) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
at jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.removeAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:268) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.
.AtmosphereRequestImpl.removeAttribute(AtmosphereRequestImpl.java:681) ~[atmosphere-runtime-3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2.jar:3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.executeAsyncWrite(DefaultBroadcaster.java:915) ~[atmosphere-runtime-3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2.jar:3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2] at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster$2.run(DefaultBroadcaster.java:477) ~[atmosphere-runtime-3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2.jar:3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(F (FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
: This message com.vaadin.flow.server.communication. AtmospherePushConnection$PushMessage@6cbb2d50 will be lost for AtmosphereResour : Failed to execute a write operation for Broadcaster /*
2023-10-02T13:11:23.767+08:00 WARN 254255 --- [here-Shared-278] org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster ce 999e5bfb-9531-4708-bff3-195024ca36d1, adding it to the BroadcasterCache 2023-10-02T13:11:23.767+08:00 WARN 254255 [here-Shared-278] org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster java.lang.IllegalStateException: The request object has been recycled and is no longer associated with this facade
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.removeAttribute(RequestFacade.java:549) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.removeAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.removeAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:268) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
at jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.removeAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:268) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.
.AtmosphereRequestImpl.removeAttribute(AtmosphereRequestImpl.java:681) ~[atmosphere-runtime-3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2.jar:3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.executeAsyncWrite(DefaultBroadcaster.java:915) ~[atmosphere-runtime-3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2.jar:3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2] at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster$2.run(DefaultBroadcaster.java:477) ~[atmosphere-runtime-3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2.jar:3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(F (FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
2023-10-02T13:11:25.767+08:00 WARN 254255 --- [here-Shared-282] org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster 2023-10-02T13:11:25.767+08:00 WARN 254255 [here-Shared-282] org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
ce 999e5bfb-9531-4708-bff3-195024ca36d1, adding it to the BroadcasterCache
: This message com.vaadin.flow.server.communication. Atmosphere PushConnection$PushMessage@48d18881 will be lost for AtmosphereResour : Failed to execute a write operation for Broadcaster /*
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The request object has been recycled and is no longer associated with this facade
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.removeAttribute(RequestFacade.java:549) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.removeAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5] .servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.removeAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:268) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
at
at
at org.atmosphere.cpr.
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequestImpl.removeAttribute(AtmosphereRequestImpl.java:681) ~[atmosphere-runtime-3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2.jar:3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2] at org.atmosphere. .cpr.
.executeAsyncWrite(DefaultBroadcaster.java:915) ~[atmosphere-runtime-3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2.jar:3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
·Defair to do ver $2.run(DefaultBroadcaster.java:477) ~[atmosphere-runtime-3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2.jar:3.0.0.slf4jvaadin2]
X
```

[image: error]

I believe the cause of this issue is the scheduler attempting to update the label every second, but I'm unsure how to fix it. I'm using Vaadin 24, and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you perform a production build and run locally?